# selecting subelements of "this" to update attributes

Tags: d3.js, this

My initial array contains quarterly data, needed to build a boxplot, faceted by ProspRating.  I created number of complex g objects (one for each ProspRating) based on the first quarter data.  Each g incapsulates simple boxplot elements - lines, rectangles, etc.)

To create the objects I used the following code (excerpt for one simple boxplot element (line.range) only):

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g.box")
.data(data10Q1)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "box")
.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + xScale(d.ProspRating) +"," + yScale(d.v_mdn) + ")"})
.each(function(d,i) {

d3.select(this)
.append('line')
.attr("class", "range")
.attr("x1", 0)
.attr("x2", 0)
.attr("y1", yScale(d.v_max) - yScale(d.v_mdn))
.attr("y2", yScale(d.v_min) - yScale(d.v_mdn))
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-width", "4px");
```

The initial boxplot based on the code works well.  Currently am trying to write a function to update the element attributes based on data for another quarter.

Excerpt from the code (for one boxplot's element (line.range) only):

```
function update (quarter) {
var filtered = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.quarter === quarter})


var boxes = d3.select("svg").selectAll("g.box")
 .data(filtered, function(d){return d.ProspRating})
  .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + xScale(d.ProspRating) +"," + yScale(d.v_mdn) + ")"})
  .each(function(d,i) {

    d3.select(this)
    .select("line.range")
    .attr("y1", yScale(d.v_max) - yScale(d.v_mdn))
    .attr("y2", yScale(d.v_min) - yScale(d.v_mdn))
```

Looks like d3.select(this).select("line.range") does not work properly.  What would be the best way to access the line.range and other similar elements to update their attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the `.enter()` after `var boxes = d3.select [...] .data [...]`